# Printing a picture using C# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner C# programmer. I want to make a simple windows form application that the user hit on a button and it shows a picture in the right side of the window! I don't know how to do it. All I've done is that I've put some buttons in a window like picture below:

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far except put the buttons in your form?

Comment: [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37xzwa15(v=vs.85).ASPX)

Comment: This might help: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

Comment: You could use a PictureBox, see [Windows Forms PictureBox - how to display the image in a certain area of the form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605687/windows-forms-picturebox-how-to-display-the-image-in-a-certain-area-of-the-for).

Comment: @JimIliadis unfortunately nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** you can use `PictureBox` Control to display the images on Windows Form.

Follow the below steps:

drag and drop the `PictureBox` control from controls `ToolBox` to `WindowsForm`.

now in button Click event handler write the following code:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("path of imge file");
    }
```

**Solution 2** : if you want to access the images from project executable you need to Add those image files as `Resources` to your project.

follow the below steps:

**Step1:**  RightClick on the `Project`

**Step2:**  Select `Properties`.

**Step3:**  Goto `Resources` tab as shown in below pic.

**Step4:**  Click on `Add Resource` Dropdown menu shown in below pic.

**Step5:**  Select `Add Existing File...`

**Step6:**  now select the file which you want to add as Resource from File Browse Dialog.

Sample ScreenShot:

[image]

And try to access the file from the Code as below:
**Note** : I have added resource with name : `sudhakar`.

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.sudhakar;
```

Comment: and I want to make the app portable. how can I do that? I mean I don't want to give address of a picture in my own computer! I want to have a .exe file that runs on every windows!

Comment: @Rasoolll: then you need to use the `Resources` , let me edit my post.

Comment: @Rasoolll: check my edited answer with `Solution 2`

Comment: I did that. I added the file named dist.png
but now this command doesn't work!
says no such file in the resource files!
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dist.png;

Comment: @Rasoolll: you should not give the file extension just give filename try this: `pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dist;` while adding the resource also you just provide name not extension, see my edited post for more information.

Comment: @Rasoolll: you are welcome :) , I'm glad tobe help of you.

Comment: Sorry that I add comment after a long time on you answer. I've been banned and cannot ask questions anymore. can you up-vote my question please? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is put a PictureBox control in your form (you can drag it from the sidebar on your left in Visual Studio). Then, at the press of a button, you could update the PictureBox image.

EDIT: Updated code to allow for using an image from your `Resources`.

Example button code (assuming the "Poisson" button is called "btnPoisson"):

```
private void btnPoisson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(YourApplicationName.Properties.Resources.nameOfImageFileInResources);
}
```

Comment: and I want to make the app portable. how can I do that? I mean I don't want to give address of a picture in my own computer! I want to have a .exe file that runs on every windows!

Comment: To do that, you would need to add the image files to your Resources or in the same directory as the executable you're supplying. Stand by for updated code.